# Publishable quality 3D figure from QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, dem, 3d-map

I tried to make a 3D map by overlaying Google Earth image on a DEM using an inbuilt 3D map feature in QGIS. Also, using qgis2threejs plugin. But I want to export the final figure to a publishable quality (more than 700dpi). All I could do is save the figure in normal quality.
Any suggestions to make a high-quality 3D map in QGIS or save the aforementioned 3D map in high resolution?

This is the image I want to export (Made using qgis2threejs):
[image: This is the image I want to export (Made using qgis2threejs]

Comment: What kind of DEM? What kind of inbuilt features? What kind of "publishable quality"? What kind of suggestions? There are a lot of points that should be clarified to be able to give an answer. Without more details, otherwiese the question risks to be closed. To avoid this unpleasant experience, edit the question to add what exactly you have, you exactly you've tried, what exactly you want to achieve and where you are stuck.

Comment: Question is updated with more details.thank you

Comment: Still not sure how the output should look like: can you post a screenshot? The low-resolution you were able to create, to see what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to export the given figure (just added) as high resolution image file.

Comment: Did you create a  print layout ? If not this should be your first steep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of quis2threejs (see the [plugin's help](https://qgis2threejs.readthedocs.io/en/docs-release/ExportSettings.html), especially the section `resampling` to see how to make setttings), you could create a new 3D view (from Menu `View`). This is a native function in QGIS, no need for a plugin.

Once you have a new 3D view, you can set the `Tile resolution` (under the tab `Terrain`, see screenshot) as well as the `Map tile resolution` (under advanced, below). Than use the small image-icon to export the 3D-view. It could be also used in a print layout (as remarked by @J.R).

However, be aware that you can only get a maximum resolution that corresponds to what you have from your data: the DEM and the satellite image.

[image]